# CSS - Can't locate the background file

Tags: html, css, notepad++

I'm trying to put in a background image for my website and the background remains white. On inspect element it says that my image could not be found.

The CSS file is linked with the HTML file because other images work, and the full directory is:
`F:\Pete\Web Design\Assignment\images\background.jpg`

Image link for the error, if it helps:

[image: 1]

```
body{
    background-image:url(images\background.jpg);
}
```

This is the code for the background image I'm using.

Comment: What is the location of your CSS-file in the directory tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your CSS in a subfolder, the following may solve the problem:

```
body{
  background-image:url("../images/background.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a *Forward-Slash* `/`

```
body{
    background-image:url(images/background.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your path in quote

```
body{
background-image:url("images/background.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is different it will not work.

F:\Pete\Web Design\Assignment\images\background.jpg

F:\Pete\Web Design\Assignment\index.html